# Input text fields string as a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text, input

I have some input text fields and a javascript. In this form input, i would like to make a text fields background color validation with specifications:

- location **DRP**, jns_sampling **Equipment**, then ha_tpc Max input value is *3200*
- location **DRP**, jns_sampling **Equipment**, and sampling_point input field contains "finish" string then ha_tpc Max input value is *100*

By the following javascript code, Max input value *3200* didn't work if i run the first specification, the second specification always be executed even though there is no "finish" string and empty field in *sampling_point* field.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="location" class="col-md-2 control-label" style="text-align:left;">location</label>    
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <select name="location" id="location" class="form-control" onselect="getWarning()">
         <option value="<?php echo $location;?>"><?php echo $location;?></option>
         <option value="WTP">WTP</option>
         <option value="DRP">DRP</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
[...]

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="table-responsive">
   [...]
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="sampling_point[]" id="sampling_point" size="17" value="<?php $a=set_value('sampling_point[0]'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
      <td>
         <select name ="jns_sampling[]" id="jns_sampling">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Equipment">Equipment</option>
            <option value="Personnel">Personnel</option>
            <option value="Environment">Environment</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="ha_tpc[]" id="ha_tpc" onkeyup="getWarning()" size="5" value="<?php $a=set_value('ha_tpc[0]'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
[...]

<script type="text/javascript">

function getWarning() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('location').value;

    switch (dropdown) {
        case 'DRP':
            var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
                if (obj[i].name == "ha_tpc[]") {
                    var hatpc = obj[i].value;
                    var type = document.getElementById('jns_sampling').value;
                    switch (type) {
                        case 'Equipment':
                            var point = document.getElementById('sampling_point').value;
                            if (hatpc == '') {
                                obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
                            } else if (hatpc > 3200) {
                                obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "#E74C3C";
                            } else if (hatpc > 100) {
                                var subjns = point.match(/finish/);
                                obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "#E74C3C";
                            } else {
                                obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
                            };
                        break;
                        case 'Personnel':
                              if (hatpc == '') {
                                obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
                            } else if (hatpc > 700) {
                                obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "#E74C3C";
                            } else {
                                obj[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
                            };
                        break;    
                        default:
                        break;   
                    }                        
                } 
            }
        break;
        default:
        break;    
    }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `type` variable to Places:

```
var type = document.getElementById('jns_sampling').value;
switch (type) {
    case 'Equipment':
    var type = document.getElementById('sampling_point').value;
```

I am not sure, but changing the value midway doesn't look like a good idea.

EDIT
You use the `name` attribute with brackets ('[]'). Try to avoid that.